# Drupal is not sending emails: Why?

Tags: 8, emails

My drupal8 is not send an email. How can I do.

It's not send in every progress (contact, user registration)

Help me please[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to determine if it's Drupal not sending the email or if it's the web server where the website is hosted.

Check if the webserver is set up with an application such as 'postfix' in order to send the email. This is easy to test if you can SSH into the server, or you can check with the hosting company.